# HTML/jQuery detach() then insertAfter() Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, I have my page set up so that when I click on a div a sub menu pops appears below the div that I clicked. I am trying to detach() the sub menu and insertAfter() and margin-left or float so that it appears to the right of the div that was clicked.

*[**Here is a picture Example of what I currently have and what I am trying to do**](http://imageshack.com/a/img834/4189/7asv.png)

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="nav-name nav-padding">Alpha</div>
        <div class="Beta">
            <div class="Delta">
                <div class="Omega">A</div>
                <div class="Omega">B</div>
                <div class="Omega">C</div>
                <div class="Omega">D</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="foo" style="display: none;"></div>   
</div>
```

script:

```
function ClickItem() {
    $('.nav-name').click(function () {
        var itemText = $(this);
        $(this).next('.delta').slideToggle('slow');
        //$(this).next('.delta').toggle('slow');
        //itemText.next().html().detach();
        //itemText.next().html().insertAfter(.nav-name).css("margin-left", "20px");

    });
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best method and if I should try to make this work. Please feel free to recommend a different method to accomplish my task if a better one is available.

Thank you

Comment: .html() returns a string, strings don't have a detach method. I don't think you need .html()

Comment: Can't you simply use **css** for positioning the submenu..?!!

Comment: Also, .next doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I tried css but I can't get it to work correctly. Example, If I use margin-left I will get something that looks like this: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img839/8719/yc8x.png
What other properties may help me display this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To detach a from Alpha and insert it after Alhpa
do like this ([check the link](http://jsfiddle.net/2yeAg/8/)):

```
    var beta = $('.Beta');
    var cloned = beta.clone();
    beta.hide();
    beta.remove();
    cloned.addClass('float_left');
    $(cloned).insertAfter('#alp');
```

I've added id alp to Your Alpha div.

**But still CSS would be a better solution!**